# ASP.net core 2.0 MVC every new database migrations includes data from previous migrations

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Hello, I have encountered a problem trying to make database migrations when adding new models or editing old ones. I am using EntityFrameworkCore. The problem is that every new migration contains the code from the Up method of the previous one.

/*
            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "UserNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers");

```
        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_AspNetUserRoles_UserId",
            table: "AspNetUserRoles");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "RoleNameIndex",
            table: "AspNetRoles");

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
            name: "Birthdate",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "FirstName",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "LastName",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            nullable: true);
            */

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Articles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                AuthorId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Content = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 25000, nullable: false),
                PublishDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                Title = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 150, nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Articles", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Articles_AspNetUsers_AuthorId",
                    column: x => x.AuthorId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

Here i am trying to migrate a new model Article to the database, but the method contains some things from the previous migration and when i try to update the database i get the following error: 
**"Cannot drop the index 'AspNetUserRoles.IX_AspNetUserRoles_UserId', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."**
If i comment the code from the previous migration and just leave the data for the appropriate model it migrates successfully. But then i add a new model "Supplement" and get the same thing with the Article migration added in the Up method:

/*
            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "UserNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers");

```
        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_AspNetUserRoles_UserId",
            table: "AspNetUserRoles");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "RoleNameIndex",
            table: "AspNetRoles");

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
            name: "Birthdate",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "FirstName",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "LastName",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            nullable: true);
            */

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Articles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                AuthorId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Content = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 25000, nullable: false),
                PublishDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                Title = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 150, nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Articles", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Articles_AspNetUsers_AuthorId",
                    column: x => x.AuthorId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Supplements",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                Description = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Price = table.Column<decimal>(nullable: false),
                Quantity = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                SupplementType = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                inStock = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Supplements", x => x.Id);
            });
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm also having the same issue.

Comment: Never did figure it out. What i did was delete/comment the fields that are already in an old migration. Other method is to delete all older migrations and just keep the latest one with all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to make sure the mappings are correct and just delete the up/down functions to have a clean state:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11763